# Using JQuery dynamic Dropdown in HTML Form (PHP)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

I wanted a dropdown that would change its options according to the value selected within an initial dropdown and i found a really good solution here on Stackoverflow. So Thanks for that first and foremost. It's exactly what i wanted. This is how it looks like:

```
  <select id="us_state"></select>
  <select id="city_name"></select> 

   var data = {
   "State 1": ["City 1", "City 2"],
   "State 2": ["City 3", "City 4"],
   "State 3": ["City 5", "City 6", "City 7"] 
   };

   var $states = $("#us_state").on("change", function() {
   var cities = $.map(data[this.value], function(city) {
   return $("<option />").text(city);
   });
   $("#city_name").empty().append(cities);
   });

   for (var state in data) {
   $("<option />").text(state).appendTo($states);
   }

   $states.change();
```

Here's the JFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8hbcP/

Since i'm pretty green in Web Application Development, i have the following questions: Can someone please help me embed this into my HTML Form which looks like this:

```
  $row1 = "
    <tr>
      <td colspan='1' align = 'left';>
        Google Search:<br>
        <select name='filters[]' id='filters' style='width:180px;' size='6'>
        " . $filter_dropdown . "
        </select>
      </td>
      <td colspan='1' align = 'left';>
         **Kategorie or Site:<br>
        <select id='us_state'>
        </select>**
      <br/>
      </td>
      <td colspan='1' align = 'left';>
         **Selection:<br>
        <select id='city_name'>
        </select>**
      </td>
      <td colspan='1' align = 'left';>
      </td>       
    </tr>";
```

You can probably deduce that i'm using PHP, so the $row is not the actual Formular, it will come into the HTML Formular as a variable. I am unable to get the dropdown to show on my page.

The second question would then be: The values inside var data {} that populate the dropdowns are supposed to be the results of a mySQL query, can someone please tell me how i can put in a variable array containing the results of the query?

Thanks once again in advance.

Comment: not clear what issue is with `how to embed` your string. As for second part you probably need to make ajax request to get city data when state is selected. Otherwise you need to dump every city into page when page is loaded which amounts to a significant amount of data

Comment: How do i get the dropdowns to show on my html is what i mean. What i have tried in my code doesnt seem to work.
    **Kategorie or Site:<br>
        <select id='us_state'>
        </select>**

Answer (score 0):

Here's the answer to your second question: get the fields you need from your mysql table (mysql_fetch_assoc), get the number of rows in your fetched array, create a form and a select element, and then create a simple for loop to go through each row, and create an option variable in each iteration.
Here's an example from my code:

```
<form action="home.php" method="post">
<select name="stores">
<? for ($i=0; $i<$numrows; $i++){
$k=$i+1;
$varname='altname'[$k]; 
$varname2='alt'.[$k];

?>
    <option value="<?echo "storename=".$$varname."&storeid=".$$varname2;?>"><?echo $$varname;?></option>

<?}?>
</select>
<input type="submit" class="button" value="SeeStore" />
</form>
```

I hope it's clear :)